# Use pip flags in a conda yml file

Tags: python, pip, conda, requirements.txt

I am creating a conda env using a `.yml` file that contains some dependencies that should be installed with pip.

```
name: test
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - geojson
  - pip
  - pip:
    - mypackage --pre
```

It seems that the --pre flag is not been considered as the stable version (v.1.52) is been installed instead of a pre-released (v.2). Of course, if I would run:

`pip install mypackage --pre`

after creating the conda env, I would get the pre-released v.2

I see from here [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6805) that the issue was discussed already so I wonder if there is any update to this? or an alternative ?

Comment: Does `pip` actually support package-specific flags in a `requirements.txt`? Conda just turns everything into a single `requirements.txt`, so I would imagine what you are seeing is a limitation of Pip.